# IF Cell Blank Move on to Next If Statment Or Query Version

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Basically, I Have 5 Cells, with a drop down list of names.
So your name may show up on a list in either cell A;E
But never more then once.
So basically i have a query Statement saying

```
=QUERY(Responses!$A$2:$AL, "Select A,T,E,AB,V,W,AC where AB is not null")
```

I need to find a way that searches
If C2:C is not blank then do above query, if it's blank then move on to Cell D2:D with a Slightly Different Query ^ etc.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/192_QI67Dg_fwvJ4SQZsvywZMJz86IkZ8fRXyJkPFyLo/edit#gid=189528795

So in S.W.A.T. Tab, im using the above query statement to check if AB is not empty it will display the list of items, problem being "E" is a possible list of names but so is C,I,K,M on the "responses" Sheet.
I've made a "Example sheet" which outlines what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Range("C2").Text=null) then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Activate
else
QUERY(Responses!$A$2:$AL, "Select A,T,E,AB,V,W,AC where AB is not null")
```

checks, if c2 is null then moves to D2, else do the query you provided.

Comment: This Doesn't Seem to work, il try and explain it a little bit better.
So C,E,G, Are all possible Name Column
If your name is in C it won't show in E or G, If it's in E it won't be in C or G etc...
I Need it to run 
[Code]=QUERY(Responses!$A$2:$AL, "Select A,T,C,AB,V,W,AC where AB is not null")  So it Grabs your name From "C"
If C Is Empty then it runs 
=QUERY(Responses!$A$2:$AL, "Select A,T,E,AB,V,W,AC where AB is not null")                                                                                                So it Grabs your Name from "E" Here
And this would then apply to "G",

Answer (score 0):

as you said:

> I need to find a way that searches If C2:C is not blank then do above
>   query, if it's blank then move on to Cell D2:D with a Slightly
>   Different Query ^ etc.

for this task you may write separate formulas to check, which column is not empty.

1. Put this formula in cell A1:

   `=if(join("", Responses!$C$2:$C, "C", if(join("", Responses!$I$2:$I, "I", ...))`
2. and then just use the result in query statement, use this formula in A2:

   `="select A, B, " & A1 & " where ..."`

the formula above can be used in `query` formula:

```
=QUERY(Responses!$A$2:$AL, A2)
```

---

When you write 3 small formulas, but not one big formula, it's easier to debug problems.

Comment: hmm im not gonna lie im having a hard time figuring out how to do this lmao.
would you be able to apply it to the link i provided under "swat" ?